# Modeling a sword handle - Problem smoothing it out

Tags: modeling

I am currently trying my first steps at modeling and currently trying out a sword.  I progressed well so far by modeling the blade and good part of the crossguard.  I decided to model half of the handle to have a good idea of the proportions I want.

Here is the work so far.
[image]

[image]

I am quite satisfied with the bottom part where the handle connects with the crossguard.  However, **I would like the upper part to finish in a circle** as the reference.  I still have not added no bevel, multiresolution or subdivision modifiers in these pics.  Nor any object shade smooth.

I have already experimented with the above modifiers but the results did not change nearly anything of the model.  No modifier seems to have an effect.  Why is this so and what can I do to smoot up the upper part of the handle?

Comment: Did you try Smooth modifier?

Comment: A smooth and subdivision modifier finally gave me the result I wanted. I also added a top ring to give it a more rounded look by adding a circle mesh to which I added a skin modifier and a smooth modifier. What do you think now? Thanks again to everyone. Learned a bit more once more :) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDgQ5.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDgQ5.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **to sphere** operation to make your selection in to sphere.

[image]

Once you start the operator, drag your mouse left and right to change the intensity.

Comment: It seems that Blender really can do anything... Didn't know about this, thanks.

Comment: @JachymMichal Nahh.... Recommend to see Houdini FX newest feature [promotion video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVlxGNLuD4U). That's - not gonna to happen in Blender for decade. But it is a little bit too complicate for sure. Keep it up, Blender!